# How can I evaluate an inequality with two inequalities in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to evaluate an inequality with two inequalities in python `20 < 3x + 5 < 26`.

With sympy I try to determine it in the following way:

```
 `20 < 3x + 5 < 26`
      `3x + 5 < 26`
```

In such a way that within the sympy syntax it remains:

```
 solve_rational_inequalities([[
     ((20, Poly(3x + 5 <)), '<'),
     ((Poly(3x + 5 <), 26), '<')]])
```

But when evaluating it, it throws me the error `ValueError: For efficiency reasons, poly should be a Poly instance`
Here the complete code:

```
 from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities
 from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_poly_inequalities
 from sympy.polys import Poly
 from sympy.abc import x
 x = Symbol('x', real=True)
 solve_rational_inequalities([[
     ((20, Poly(3x + 5 <)), '<'),
     ((Poly(3x + 5 <), 26), '<')]])
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Beforehand thank you very much. Greetings.

Comment: Please confirm: "20 < 3x + 5 < 26" means 3x+5 is between 20 and 26 (not inclusive).  Or, put another way, both 20<3x+5 AND 3x+5<26.

Comment: Yes, I confirm (20<3x+5<26)

Comment: You have some idea?